# Output printed string into txt

Tags: python, string, list, txt

I have

```
brand = ['Apple','Oppo','Huawei']
model = ['IPhone SE', 'K10 5G', 'Honor X7']
price = ['400','380','160']

for (i, j, k) in zip(brand, model, price):
    print('brand : ' + i + '\nmodel : ' + j + '\nprice : ' + k)
```

and got

```
brand : Apple
model : Iphone SE
price : '400'

brand : Oppo
model : K10 5G
price : '380'

brand : Huawei
model : Honor X7
price : '160'
```

and I wanted to output the result into a txt file, I tried

```
import sys    

sys.stdout = open("test.txt", "w")    
for (i, j, k) in zip(brand, model, price):
    print('brand : ' + i + '\nmodel : ' + j + '\nprice : ' + k)
sys.stdout.close()
```

but it only save the last output.

Comment: This works fine for me.

Comment: "it only save the last output.", do you mean from running the application mulitple times?

Comment: Welcome back to Stack Overflow. As a refresher, please read [ask]. What is your *question*? Please don't just describe a problem - make it clear *how to see the problem*, *exactly* what happens when you do this, and *exactly what should happen instead* (and how is that different?). Then ask a specific question, starting with a question word like "how" or "why", and ending with a question mark (`?`).

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
with open('test.txt', 'w') as file:
  for (i, j, k) in zip(brand, model, price):
      file.write('brand : ' + i + '\nmodel : ' + j + '\nprice : ' + k + '\n')
```

Comment: thanks, where can I find the test.txt file after that?

Comment: In the folder where scrip file is located. If you want change folder, specifi path for example `with open('C:\\my-folder\\test.txt', 'w')`

Comment: You can specifi path. Refresh page because I have edited the comment above

Comment: yeap, need to specific path, else it won't appear in my desktop, thanks

Comment: "where can I find the test.txt file after that?" In the same place as with the code that you tried.